# Ajax call return undefined when extract the url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the list of 7 blocks in my PHP using 'createDivs' class. I can get the elements in the html source when I press on the enter button of the keyboard on each block. I'm trying to find out how I can extract the HREF URL from another php page when using textFromBlock variable to find the match element, so I can extract the URL using Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("div").hide();
  $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row).addClass( "yellowbg" );
});


$(document).keyup(function(event)
{
  var yellowbg = $(".yellowbg");

  if (event.keyCode == 13)
  {  //enter
    alert("enter tested");
    getStreamLink();
  } 
}


function getVideoLink()
{
  var i=0;
  $.ajax({
  url:'myscript.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'',
  success: function(data)
  {
    var $data = $(data);
    var textFromBlock = $('.yellowbg').html();
    var stream1 = $data.filter("#Stream 1").html();
    alert(stream1);
    alert(textFromBlock);
  }   
  });
}
```

Here's a sample of what the HTML is look like:

```
<p id='block'>Block 1<p id='links'>http://mysite.com/get-listing.php?block=Block 1</p><a href="">Stream 1</a>
<p id='block'>Block 2<p id='links'http://mysite.com/get-listing.php?block=Block 2</p><a href="">Stream 1</a>
<p id='block'>Block 3<p id='links'>http://mysite.com/get-listing.php?block=Block 3</p><a href="">Stream 1</a>
<p id='block'>Block 4<p id='links'>http://mysite.com/get-listing.php?block=Block 4</p><a href="rtmp://$OPT:rtmp-raw=rtmp://www.myvideolink.com/test.flv">Stream 1</a>
<p id='block'>Block 5<p id='links'>http://mysite.com/get-listing.php?block=Block 6</p><a href="">Stream 1</a>
```

In this case, when I press on the down arrow button of the keyboard to get on the Block 6 and press the enter button, it will get the elements from the Block 6. I want to find the match element in my myscript.php using textFromBlock then extract the URL to input in the alert message to something is like "rtmp://$OPT:rtmp-raw=rtmp://www.myvideolink.com/test.flv".

However, when I press on the enter button, I got the alert message that it said "undefined". I have checked the tag name and I got the tag name correcr, but I have no idea why I still received the undefined. Does anyone know why and what I have done it wrong?

Comment: Is that `<p>` missing a `>` or is that a typo?

Comment: @RUJordan i don't think the `<p>` have missing a `>`. I think my code may got it wrong or missing something, but i'm not so sure.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `.filter("#Stream 1")`? Do you wish to select the elements that contain the text "Stream 1" (there are 5 of them, which one do you want)? Do you wish to select the containing `p` tags? `.filter("#Stream 1")` doesn't make a lick of sense.

Comment: Well I'm trying to accomplish with one of the element when I press on the enter button of the keyboard to find the match element in another php script then get the stream link from the href tag '<a id="aTest" href="linkgoeshere">Stream 1</a>. here's two links for e.g: http://testbox.elementfx.com/blocks.php and http://testbox.elementfx.com/database.php. hope you get what i'm mean?

Comment: just to point out... the link isn't actually in the `a href` tag... it's right after the `links` paragraph starts.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin yeah...how i can get the link in the href tag from another php page? i tried this: var stream1 = $data.find('a:contains(#Stream 1)').attr('href');, i still get undefined. any idea?

Comment: `$data.filter('.links').text()` or something.... oh, that won't even work because you're re-using the element ID and `links` isn't even a class...

Comment: @gloomy.penguin thanks for your help. I can see the problem is fixed, but i can't get extract the href link to input in the alert message. I still get the same error of `undefined` using the code `var stream1 = $data.find('a:contains(#Stream 1)').attr('href');`. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than this:

```
$data.filter("#Stream 1").html();
```

You want to get the 'href' from the element which contains "Stream 1" like this:

```
$data.find('a:contains(Stream 1)').attr('href')
```

Comment: this will work if you do something like... `<p class='block'>Block 6<p class='links'></p><a href="http://mysite.com/get-listing.php?block=Block6">Stream 1</a></p>`... and move that link to where it probably should be

Comment: @gloomy.penguin thanks for your help. I think I may have a problem. How do I get the `<p class` to work on this code: `$doc filter using this:  $doc.filter('p#blocks').each(function(index)??, i tried to use `p class#blocks` but it doesn't work. when I used `p #blocks` without the class when I had the tag `<p id=blocks`, it was working fine. How I can use the class in my current code?